# Localising Radio Buttons in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, localization, globalization

How do you go about localising radio button items based on strings contained in a global resource file? I have managed to localise labels and buttons by editing the `(Expressions).Text` property to refer to this global resource file, but I can't seem to be able to do it for radio buttons or other list-based controls. Do I have to bind them programmatically or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: please show how you are setting Expression ? There must be the problem in your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expression is not correct as you have not shown to us. There is difference between Local and global resources when we use..

here is how to Get Global Resources

```
Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalRes, NameOfKey %>"
```

Answer (score 1):

With localising list based controls, you best "short stick" option is to bind to the data set in the proper language. I am sure you could create a class derived from the list and control it another way, but massaging the data prior to bind is the quickest method. I don't know of a "better" way.